# How to add a relationship so that related object would appear in a certain position in ActiveRecord CollectionProxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-2.2

### Situation:

I have 4 models with relationships like these:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
  belongs_to :c
  belongs_to :d
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :as, dependent: :destroy
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :d
end

class D < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

### Problem:

I need to relate model A object `a` to model B object `b` but I also need to set a position for object `a` where to appear in [ActiveRecord CollectionProxy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) when calling `b.as` and it won't work. **All attempts to add object `a` to a certain position in `a.bs` result end up with having newly added `a` at the end**. Is it possible at all? I know there are possibilities for defining ordering in arrays and while querying, but is it possible to define the ordering directly when adding new relationship?

### Example:

Model B object `b` has 3 model A objects.

```
b.as
  => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [
    #<A id: 39038, quantity: 3.0 created_at: "2016-02-01 15:51:26", updated_at: "2016-02-01 15:51:26", d_id: 4144, c_id: nil, b_id: 81218>, 
    #<A id: 39039, quantity: 2.0, created_at: "2016-02-01 15:51:26", updated_at: "2016-02-01 15:51:26", d_id: 4145, c_id: nil, b_id: 81218>,
    #<A id: 39040, quantity: 2.0, created_at: "2016-02-01 15:51:26", updated_at: "2016-02-01 15:51:26", d_id: 4145, c_id: 1590, b_id: 81218>]>
```

I create fourth model A object `a` and I need it to appear on second place when calling `b.as` like this:

```
a = A.create(quantity: 4.0, d: D.find(4144), c: C.find(1612), b: b)
```

Basically the ordering should be defined like this:

```
b.as
=>
  a1: d_id: 4144, c_id: nil
  a2: d_id: 4144, c_id: 1612
  a3: d_id: 4145, c_id: nil
  a4: d_id: 4145, c_id: 1590
```

...meaning that every `a` object with same `d_id` attribute should be grouped together meanwhile having those `a`s that have `c_id.nil?` in first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add method will always add it to the end of the list. You need some sort of a position attribute to achieve what you want. If you don't want to implement that yourself, you can take a look at [Acts as list gem](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=act%20as%20list). Another option is to add a `default_scope { order: :key_to_order_by }` on the As model.

Comment: With a little modification `scope :in_order, -> { order("d_id, id") }` did what I needed exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
has_many :as, -> { order(d_id: :asc, c_id: :asc) }
```

Should be close, except nil is ordered at the end after the highest `cd_id`. That's *postgres* doing the sort, so I don't know if there is much you can do there.

Comment: This lead me to errors where I had declarations like `b.reload` while new `b` was not saved yet (error: `Couldn't find B without an ID`). I guess I can't order sub-objects if they don't know the parent-object ID?

Comment: Not using `order` that translates to a SQL statement. Why where you reloading `b` if it hasn't being saved. Reload is meant to reinitialize the record from the DB, the documentation says: "Reloads the record from the database.

This method finds record by its primary key ..."